# Golang Docker Container Not Restarting in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, rabbitmq, restart

I want to be able to restart a golang docker file on failure to connect to rabbitmq as outined here: ([Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) see answer by: svenhornberg).
Unfortunately my golang container will exit but never restart and I don't know why.

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:3.4.1'
    container_name: 'datastore'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  rabbitmq:
    restart: always
    tty: true
    image: rabbitmq:3.7-management-alpine
    hostname: "rabbit"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672" 
      - "5672:5672"
    labels:
      NAME: "rabbitmq"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq-isolated.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:15672"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
  api:
    restart: always
    tty: true
    container_name: 'api'
    build: '.'
    working_dir: /go/src/github.com/patientplatypus/project
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - './:/go/src/github.com/patientplatypus/project'
      - './uploads:/uploads'
      - './scripts:/scripts'
      - './templates:/templates'
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
      - "rabbitmq"
```

Docker file:

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/patientplatypus/project
COPY . .

RUN go get github.com/imroc/req
<...more go gets...>
RUN go get github.com/joho/godotenv

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT  [ "fresh" ]
```

Here is my golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Golang server started")
    godotenv.Load()
    fmt.Println("now doing healthcheck on rabbit")
    exec.Command("docker-compose restart api")
    os.Exit(1)
  <...>
```

And here is my terminal output (golang never restarts after rabbit called):

```
api         | 23:23:00 app         | Golang server started
api         | 23:23:00 app         | now doing healthcheck on rabbit
rabbitmq_1  | 
rabbitmq_1  |   ##  ##
rabbitmq_1  |   ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.7.11. Copyright (C) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
rabbitmq_1  |   ##########  Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
rabbitmq_1  |   ######  ##
rabbitmq_1  |   ##########  Logs: <stdout>
<...more rabbit logging...>
```

I'm very confused on how to get this to work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The `exec.Command` was incorrectly implemented, however `os.Exit(1)`, `log.Fatal`, and `log.Panic` exit the container, but the container does not restart. Still confused.

Comment: Never ignore errors. Your `exec.Command` call is wrong

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: How exactly are you invoking `docker-compose`?  (Some invocations [can cause `restart:` to be ignored](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart).)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure I understand the question. I use `docker-compose up --build`, and each of my containers is tagged, as you can see above, with `restart: always`.

Comment: Ah I see `Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file. Use restart_policy instead.` I don't believe this situation applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Docker documentation says:](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

> A restart policy only takes effect after a container starts successfully. In this case, starting successfully means that the container is up for at least 10 seconds and Docker has started monitoring it. This prevents a container which does not start at all from going into a restart loop.

Since the Go code you show exits basically immediately, it never meets this 10-second-minimum rule.

You can force Go to wait until the process has been alive a minimum of 10 seconds by using [time.After](https://godoc.org/time#After) somewhat like:

```golang
ch := time.After(10 * time.Second)
defer (func() { fmt.Println("waiting"); <-ch; fmt.Println("waited") })()
```

That is, create a channel that will receive an event after 10 seconds, and then actually receive it (immediately if it's happened, waiting if not) before `main` returns.  From playing with https://play.golang.org/p/zGY5jFWbXyk, the one trick is that there needs to be some observable effect after receiving from the channel or else it doesn't actually wait.

Comment: Thanks for digging that restart blurb up, very helpful. I think the easiest way to do this will be to test the connection to the rabbit uri at the beginning of main and on an error sleep 10 seconds. Thanks!